# Return Oracle SQL Columns that doesnt have null value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, null

I have table with 100 columns

```
select * from <table> where id = 'xxxx'
```

the result i got is fine, however there are some columns that are null value I don't need. How do I filter my select * to just return columns with value.

```
id     col1 col2 col3 col4 col...100
xxxx   aaaa bbbb null null
```

output only columns with value for id is returned

```
id   col1 col2
xxxx aaaa bbbb
```

Comment: Specify only id,col1 and col2 columns instead of * in select query.

Comment: What do you want to get if `col1` is null for the row with id=1 and not null for the row with id=2?

Comment: but i dont know all column names to type and probably there a lot of them to list there must be col 44 w/c is not null or col99.. I just like columns that doesnt have null

Comment: my reference is column id w/c is 'xxxx'

Comment: Again: what do you want to see if a column has a null value in one row and a not null value in another row. But in short: you can't do what you want with a simple SQL statement. Your only option is to actually type the column names (most SQL clients will help you with that by providing some kind of auto-completion). Also: the requirement _could_ indicate that your data model might be wrong. Maybe those columns should be rows instead...

Comment: that column shouldn't be returned, just to add there's only one row.